# Get request from android app to wamp does not working

Tags: android, http, httpwebrequest, wamp

I am working on an android app, but I don't have internet conection so I am using WAMP local server.
If I want to show web page I used loadURL`(http://10.0.2.2/wamp/www/....)` and page shows, WebView working.

But when I tried sending some request to this page, that did not work, I want to show source code, this page didn't work, I used code available on net for the same, but that did not work too. 
I already have added Internet permission.

I don't have experience with WAMP.

Any help is appreciated!!

And sorry , my English is not good:)

Comment: make sure u r setting up local wamp setup properly what kind of error u get from android app? can u post here?

Comment: i dont get error only white page. I only setting in wamp that server is public. Must i setting something else?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: i must use some php script in my android app?

Comment: yes thats how u can communicate ?u didnt used ? what were u using then?

Comment: only sending request to url in android project.

Comment: which url?u create service?right?

Comment: yes i create, and sending request to url http://10.0.2.2/wamp/www/....

Comment: okk can u post code u tryied or rather refer tut above call service

Answer (score 0):

May be an error in your url.

> Try `http://10.0.2.2/....` instead of `http://10.0.2.2/wamp/www/....`

Also make sure you set INTERNET PERMISSION.